Quarkus - problem image with Qute and mailer and set image file for template (test unit)
i have a problem when execute a service. My image is into the path META-INF/resources/images/apoio_logo.png.
public Uni<Void> enviarNotificacaoMQ(Email email) {
        String body = engine.getTemplate(email.getTemplate()).data("email", email).render();
        Log.info("***** preparando para enviar e-mail AWS *****");
        Mail mail = prepararEmail(email, body);
        Uni<Void> enviado = reactiveMailer.send(mail);
        Log.info("***** email enviado com sucesso *****");
        return enviado;
    }

    private Mail prepararEmail(Email email, String body) {
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        List<String> to = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> cc = new ArrayList<>();
        to.add(email.getEmail());
        cc.add(email.getEmailCC());
        mail.setTo(to);
        Optional.of(cc).ifPresent(mail::setBcc);
        Optional.of(email.getEmailsCCO()).ifPresent(mail::setBcc);
        mail.setSubject(email.getAssunto());
        mail.setHtml(body);
        mail.addInlineAttachment("apoio_cotacoes.png",
                new File("images/apoio_cotacoes.png"),
                "image/png", "<apoio_logo>");
        return mail;
    }

when i run "mvn test" return this error

Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/fabio/Documents/REMSoft/apoio-notificacao/images/apoio_cotacoes.png

Here is the template
<div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="cid:apoio_logo">
</div>

Does anyone know a solution? This occurs only in test mode?

Where have you placed images/apoio_cotacoes.png?

In the resources folder /home/fabio/Documents/REMSoft/apoio-notificacao/src/main/resources/images/apoio_cotacoes.png

I change the path to /src/images/apoio_cotacoes.png and resolve the problem

Please add that as answer as it will help future users :)

I change the path to /src/images/apoio_cotacoes.png and resolve the problem!
